# iModelJS - How do I display a model without going through iModelHub?

Tags: web-applications, imodeljs

...if that is possible?

What I'd like to do is almost the same as the [Simple Viewer App](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs-samples/blob/master/interactive-app/simple-viewer-app/README.md) - show a model of some type of bim-file with metadata one display at the side, for the web.

However, in the normal setup with iModelJS one has to get an account at iModelJS/Bentley and upload the file to their servers. It also seems you need an account with them to just view the model.

At times iModelJS says it is [necessary](https://www.imodeljs.org/learning/frontend/) to register with them to use their service, and that all iModels must come from a briefcase from iModelHub. But Keith Bentley himself [says](https://youtu.be/5iglYhQmv6U?t=114) you don't have to be connected to any particular server to use it. But I can't find that information in their documentation.

So, is this possible, and if so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand the framework imodel.js

First one need to think about - what is an .imodel. According to the docs:

*An iModel is a distributed relational database, based on SQLite, with a schema defined by BIS. An iModel holds information about a single infrastructure asset. iModels may contain physical and functional models, drawings, specifications, analytical models, etc.*

However the .imodel is used by Bentley in an ecosystem called [imodel 2.0](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwje3ICypOLmAhVk1qYKHe-fBEUQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprod-bentleycdn.azureedge.net%2Fen%2Fperspectives-and-viewpoints%2Ftopics%2Fviewpoint%2Fwp-imodel-2-platform&usg=AOvVaw3U4vsk9o9eEJLLQdhNALRy)

In the imodel 2.0 ecosystem, the "Bentley way" of accsessing the imodel database is connecting to it via a *Connected Project*. By using the *Connected Project* multiple other services such as cloud hosting and cloud processing can be used in the Project.

As I understand it the sample-viewer app is designed to be a part of the *Connected Project* ecosystem.

To be able to parse an imodel-db without a *Connected Project* I think there is need for some reverse engineering.

Since the framework for parsing the database is open source the best way is to read the docs to see what is possible

I would first focus my attention to the [backend module](https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output//learning/backend/)

Reading the chapter "Opening an iModel via the IModelDb class" in the DB it gives hints on how to proceed. To be able to acces an imodel without a connected project, one way could be to think of it as a "snapshot" .imodel. A non-linked "dead" model that is stored locally.

*The IModelDb class also provides methods for opening, closing, and accessing a snapshot iModel. A snapshot iModel is a file that is disconnected from iModelHub and therefore does not have a change timeline. Once created, a snapshot iModel is read-only and cannot be changed. This makes snapshot iModels ideal for archival or data transfer purposes.*

[Further instructions on creating a snapshot imodel](https://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/b/microstation_blog/posts/publishing-an-imodel-in-bentley-view)

When a .imodel is locally stored the imodel.js library should be able to parse the data and send it to the frontend.

Do you have a sample .imodel 2.0 that you can try to parse using [ECSQL](https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output/learning/ecsql/) and the backend module?
Just to see if you can get some data out of it?

Comment: Thanks for the info! Hm...yes, it seems that the snapshot iModel could be used to display the data. But, it seems this part of the project is [not open source](https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output/learning/backend/accessingimodels/), but proprietary, and you [cannot reverse engineer it](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/blob/master/core/backend/src/imodeljs-native-LICENSE.md).

However, it seems you should be able to open a snapshot locally. But, I was looking to use this software with a hosting service, but it can't be proprietary. Ah well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction that a snapshot iModel be used locally. The right-to-run required to use the native modules (that are implemented in C++ and not part of the open source codebase) is granted for snapshot iModels unconditionally, including on a hosting service.

Comment: They don't seem to be. The [license text](https://github.com/imodeljs/imodeljs/blob/master/core/backend/src/imodeljs-native-LICENSE.md) of the `@bentley/imodeljs-native` module (which is needed for all backend-operations) specifically says that one "may not [u]se the software for commercial software hosting services".

Comment: That restriction was inadvertent and has now been removed.